Need help to spec components for a flash joule heating power supply
I'm trying to build a flash joule heating power supply that I have seen used successfully. I unfortunately have limited knowledge of the specs on some of the components used. I would also like to get input on improving/refining the circuit and components where possible.
The power supply is basically a half-wave rectification pulse generator as I understand it. The overall design takes 120 V AC supplied to a 0-140 V AC Variac. The output of the Variac will be connected to the primary of a “step up” MOT transformer.
The MOT transformer secondary will supply AC voltage to a diode with capability of reaching ~240 VD C. Considering the efficiency loss of the half-wave rectifier of: 40.6%, I would need to supply an AC voltage of: ~584 V AC.
So I have been trying to find a diode capable of handling this, and I came across these half-wave rectifier modules used for motor brakes that seem like they should work for my desired application. Example:
600 V Half Wave Rectifier
Once the voltage has been rectified to ~240 V DC the circuit connects to a capacitor bank with 6 total capacitors. 2 sets of 3 capacitors wired in parallel. The two sets of 3 parallel capacitors are then wired in series. Each capacitor is rated for 250 V DC and 27000 μF. Overall capacitance of all 6 as wired above is: 40500 μF.
Next is a dump resistor I have estimated to be in the 300-400 Ω range so that voltage drops in the neighborhood of 1V per second. The resistor will be the wire-wound type.
Next in the circuit in the +240 V DC lead will be a puck type SCR diode. The gate will be fired with a push button switch connected to two AA batteries and ground for ~3 V DC. I am still trying to figure out exactly how to size and find the proper SCR for this.
Once the SCR is fired, the goal is to send a ~240 V DC / 1000 A pulse into a tungsten electrode which has a powdered material sandwiched between it and another Tungsten electrode connected to ground. This high voltage/high current arc provides the reaction. The powdered material is compressed between the electrodes until a resistance of 2 ohms is reached.
Here's a basic schematic I drew that I believe is correct for this set up. Hopefully it will give some clarity on all the details given above:

Any input is welcome. I need to verify if the motor brake rectifier I linked to will actually work for what I intend? I could also use any input on sizing the SCR Diode.
Also, if anyone sees a better way to do this or any improvements or problems, please let me know. I know this fairly crude at this point, I'm just trying to spec components at this time.
A quick disclaimer, I understand that these voltages and currents are very lethal. I have experience working with high voltages and currents. I will exercise all safety precautions and insulate/isolate anywhere that needs it.
Thanks for reading my massive post.
ETA, I forgot to mention the order of operation for this circuit. With the SCR in open state, the Variac is slowly increased. The VDC is monitored at the output of the half-wave rectifier until it reaches ~240 V DC. Once at ~240 V DC, the Variac is turned to 0VAC and the voltage bleeds down through the dump resistor at around 1VDC per second until it reaches exactly 237 V DC. Once at 237 V DC, the push button switch is closed, sending ~3 V DC to the SCR gate, closing the SCR Diode and firing the pulse.

November 13, 2024
Just wanted to update this post. Since my original post I have acquired a power supply that converts 120VAC to to an adjustable DC output range of: 117VDC-330VDC @ 200mA. So for the time being I've shelved the MOT transformer and rectifier and hope to be able to charge the capacitor bank with this power supply.
The power supply has an adjustable resistor "trimpot" built into the board that varies the output voltage. I can adjust the voltage to the target of ~240VDC. I also added a push button disconnect switch, rated for 600VAC/250VDC, to disconnect the power supply from the capacitor bank once it's been charged to the appropriate level.
Then I allow the resistor to bleed the voltage down to my target voltage and fire the SCR with a momentary push button switch being fed from a seperate 3VDC power supply. This discharges the capacitor bank into the material.
I'm still working out some of the details but I should be ready to start testing this project soon. I'll post results as I proceed with commissioning everything, good or bad.

At these powers, a full bridge rectifying should be used ... Note that the 2 "capacitors" should have paralleled resistors to equalize their own voltages. The drive voltage is not well wired ( between gate and source of SCR !)

Is  "MOT transformer" a Microwave Oven Transformer Transformer?

And what will this accomplish in the end?

Note also that the output nominal voltage of a MOT is 2100 V rms ...

Antonio 51, I appreciate the input I had been thinking of installing resistors on each capacitor so I will plan to do that. Also I believe I drew the gate trigger circuit improperly so I will address that also. I also understand the high ratio of the MOT.

MrGerber, yes MOT = Microwave Oven Transformer.

winny, you can use this to make turbostratic graphene among other things. You can also use it to reclaim the raw materials in Li batteries, circuit boards, etc. Just requires grinding the material up.

Antonio51, I forgot to mention that I had been exploring the use of a full wave bridge rectifier vs half wave. I am not sure why the original builder went with half wave rectification? Thanks again.

How long does your pulse need to be? Might this be a job for pfn (pulse forming network)?

Interesting! Is your present setup working or do you need assistance selecting an SCR? Do you have any idea on the 1000 A waveshape? This in order to calculate I^2t for an SCR.

@D Duck, from what I have gathered the pulse duration should be ~5ms. Also the pulse forming network is interesting and something I'm looking into, thanks for the idea.

@winny, I'm in need of assistance selecting the SCR. I am currently trying to get familiar with all the specs that go into sizing the press pack SCR. I'm currently unsure of the wave form but I'm working on trying to figure that out.

Find out. Calculate I^2t product. Search for datasheets and make sure the single pulse (half-wave) it can handle is more than your calculated value.
